# ffmpeg not splitting into EXACT same length chunks

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-processing

I am trying to use ffmpeg to split a long video into exactly 20second long clips, and accomplishing that by:
inside docker as a python sub-process

```
subprocess.run(["/usr/sbin/ffmpeg",
        "-i", video_loc,
        "-async", "1",
        "-map", "0",
        "-segment_time", "20",
        "-f", "segment", 
        "-reset_timestamps", "1",
        "n-%05d.mp4"], cwd=r'/clips')
```

My problem is that each are roughly 20seconds, some are as low as 10seconds, some as high as 27 seconds, i would say most are around 16-23. Is there something else that I can do to ensure the split of exactly 20 seconds? I am open to any technique possible, aside from anything manual...

Comment: Add `"-force_key_frames", "expr:gte(t\,n_forced*20)",`. ffmpeg ver needed is 3.0 or later

Comment: Perfect, although the expression above resulted in <code>Missing ')' or too many args in 'gte(t\,n_forced*20)'</code>, while removing the backslash with: <code>expr:gte(t,n_forced*20)</code> worked great! they are all 20seconds long, with a degree of error at most (so far) 2/100 of second

Answer (score 0):

I have another approach that you can try 
Let us say you have a video called 'input.mp4' and you want to split it to "n" number of videos and each are 20 sec long.

`ffmpeg -ss 00:00:00.000 -i input.mp4 -ss 00:00:19.000 -t 00:00:20.000 -c copy v1.mp4
ffmpeg -ss 00:00:20.000 -i input.mp4 -ss 00:00:39.000 -t 00:00:20.000 -c copy v2.mp4` 
and so on ..

Answer (score 0):

I wish I had the reputation to leave a comment to compound upon Gyan's comment instead of leaving an answer but alas I don't, so this will have to do.

The reason you're still experiencing some degree of variation is likely because the framerate of the input source is fractional and not whole. For example - 59.94 or 29.97 as opposed to 30 or 60.

I have tested segmentation and forcing keyframes extensively and found both only work "perfectly" when the source videos FPS is a whole number. Simply force your source video to an integer framerate so frames are duplicated and you will experience much more consistency in terms of length. Of course with the obvious caveat that your output now contains duplicated frames. The reason I have perfectly in quotation marks is because there is still a degree of variation extremely infrequently, I have only noticed it twice in my case.

That being said you may rather have slight variation in segment length as opposed to duplicated frames. But if you were segmenting multiple sources at once it is basically required that all sources have integer framerates or slowly over-time, when comparing like numbered parts, you will experience desynchronization.

Long story short, if length consistency is the #1 priority utilize both -r [desired integer framerate] and expr:gte(t,n_forced*20) after the input.

Comment: Although Gyan's answer, and my own subsequent comment worked for forcing 20seconds, your suggestion of fractional framerate of the input source is interesting. I will look into it and then comment back.

Comment: `FFmpeg cannot force a keyframe on a duplicated frame` --> no, frame drop/dupe logic is disassociated from encoding. The encoder or ffmpeg don't care. Try this: `ffmpeg -loop 1 -framerate 1 -i a_single_image.jpg -r 25 -force_key_frames expr:not(mod(n,38)) -t 10 out.mp4` All manually designated KFs are on dupes.

Comment: Forcing `r 30` on a 29.97 fps input results in only one dupe every 900 odd frames.

Comment: Thanks for chiming in Gyan, I should have thought to test that before theorizing, very interesting. I wonder why forcing the keyframes isn't completely consistent even with an integer framerate... Although it's really a non-issue, as I said in my literal thousands of hours of recording I have only noticed my parts cut 1 frame early twice after forcing keyframes and an integer framerate, just perplexing. I'll edit that out of the above answer.

Comment: @jupiar something else I just noticed - I was never able to get -reset_timestamps 1 to work while outputting mp4, had to switch to ts. Maybe this was an issue exclusive to me but I did test on multiple computers at the time, was a few versions back. From what I understand ts is just more friendly when it comes segmentation. The only issue is ffmpeg adds delay to the beginning of ts files, not sure why, but I found `-segment_format_options max_delay=0` alleviated the issue.