# FFmpeg not splitting videos precisely

Tags: python, ffmpeg, subprocess

I was trying to use FFmpeg to split videos into 30s segments, here is the full code:

```py
from tkinter import filedialog, Tk
import subprocess
import os
Tk().withdraw()
path_to_video = filedialog.askopenfilename()

segment_duration = input("Enter each segment duration in second: ")

os.chdir(os.path.dirname(__file__))
subprocess.run([
    "E:\\Programs\\FFmpeg\\ffmpeg-master-latest-win64-gpl\\bin\\ffmpeg.exe", 
    "-i", path_to_video, 
    "-c:", "copy", 
    "-map", "0", 
    "-segment_time", segment_duration, 
    "-f", "segment", 
    "-reset_timestamps", "1",
    "Output_%03d.mp4"])
```

But it actually splits it into videos with really low precision, how can I fix it? [Another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51360136/ffmpeg-not-splitting-into-exact-same-length-chunks) regarding this topic suggested adding this line:

```py
"-force_key_frames", f"expr:gte(t,n_forced*{segment_duration})",
```

But it didn't really work...

Comment: What do you mean by low precision? Do you mean that it's off by one frame, or off by more?

Comment: I mean i get videos that aren't exactly 30 seconds long, they range from 26 to 32s

Comment: What's your ffmpeg version?

Comment: when I run ffmpeg in the cmd it says ffmpeg version N-109185-g14c6093528-20221123

Comment: That's the version number? I was expecting something like 5.1.2.

Comment: I don't really know how to get that although I can say for sure that it is the win64 gpl download from here https://github.com/BtbN/FFmpeg-Builds/releases/tag/autobuild-2022-11-23-12-36

It is basically the latest

Comment: So yeah I assume it's the 5.12

Comment: One comment suggests this could be caused by a non-integer framerate. Can you check that? See [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/110264/how-to-find-frames-per-second-of-any-video-file) for how to check framerate.

Comment: if I run ffmpeg -i myvideofile.mp4 it says its 29.97 fps.
Sorry for the delay, but I had school this morning :)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51372315/530160